# Saving background and font color to local storage from a dynamically generated react component

Tags: reactjs

I am working on A note-taking app with React, I have an issue  with Persistence data(LS), that I wanted to save the selected color of each note  into Local storage, but for some reason, the colors are being replaced when I click on each note color, Is there any way to store each color in LS, I appreciate for any help, I tried like this;

```js
export const Note = ({ note, deleteNote, onEditNote }) => {
  const [background, setBackground] = React.useState('#fff');
  const [fontColor, setFontColor] = React.useState('#000');

  const setStyle = (background, fontColor) => {
    setBackground(background);
    setFontColor(fontColor);
  };

    useEffect(() => {
    const data1 = localStorage.getItem('bg_color');

    if (data1) {
      setBackground(JSON.parse(data1));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data2 = localStorage.getItem('fonts_color');

    if (data2) {
      setBackground(JSON.parse(data2));
    }
  }, []); 

     useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('bg_color', JSON.stringify(background));
  }, [background]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('fonts_color', JSON.stringify(fontColor));
  }, [fontColor]);
 

    useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('fonts_color', JSON.stringify(fontColor));
  }); 

return (
    <>
      <Card
        style={{
          width: 300,
          height: 'auto',
          fontSize: '1rem',
          wordWrap: 'break-word',
          margin: '0',
          marginRight: '15px',
          background: `${background}`,
          color: `${fontColor}`,
        }}
      >
        <h3>{note.title}</h3>
        <p>{note.text}</p>
//Buttons
 <Buttons>
        <div>
          <Tooltip title="High-Priority">
            <button
              className="color-info"
              onClick={() => {
                setStyle(colors[0].backgroundColor,colors[0].backgroundColor);
              }}
              style={redButton}
            ></button>
          </Tooltip>

          <Tooltip title="Medium-Priority">
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setStyle('#ffbe76', '#000');
              }}
              style={orangeButton}
            ></button>
          </Tooltip>
```

[image: screen shoot]

Comment: What about store an array of your cards styles in LS ? localStorage.setItem('cardsInfos', [{bg_color:"#fff', text_color:"#000", text:"", ...whatever}, {{bg_color:"#ededed', text_color:"#a2a2a2", text:"", ...whatever},...])

Comment: Also you can prefix your attributes by the card index like localStorage.setItem(card_index+'_bg_color', ...)

Comment: If the item name in the local storage is `bg_color` and `fonts_color` then it's the same for every item. Not sure how you store the notes, but you probably should store them as an array of objects, with ids, content, and colours.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros, notes are stored as an array of objects, but my problem is how can I specify a specific color for a specific card also save that color in LS

Comment: Do you store the notes in LS too?

Comment: Yes, they are stored already,